# Non socket based Java Server

Tags: java, webserver

Kicking it old school: I'm using Java SE 5 (or java v1.5) (please don't tell me to upgrade, because for what I'm working on [which is private] I need to use this version of java).

I need help setting up a web client/server application. Every variation I've looked for online has narrowed down to using websockets/sockets, however the version of java I'm using does not have sockets yet.

Does anyone have a tutorial for setting up a client/server model application not using sockets, or some sample code that can point me in the correct direction?

EDIT:
Okay, so apparently my version of java does have sockets. I'll look into that more. However, now I'm just curious, how does one create a java server not using sockets?

Comment: Of course Java 5 has sockets, they've been around since JDK 1.0: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Java v1.5 has sockets...

Comment: `client/server` implies you are using a `connection based` protocol of which `TCP` is the most common.  The way to use TCP is with plain old `Socket` or NIO `SocketChannels` both have been around for years before Java 5.0.  If you upgraded to Java 7 you could use NIO2, but I wouldn't bother unless you have Infiniband (most likely, you don't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need sockets. [They serve as the end-points to the connection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). Although, you can use alternatives to the blocking `Socket` and `ServerSocket` implementations.

NIO (New IO) uses channels. It allows for non-blocking I/O:

```
class Server {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
          ssc.configureBlocking(false);

          while(true) {
               SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();

               if(sc != null) {
                    //handle channel
               }
          }
     }
}
```

**Using a Selector** (optional, but recommended)

You could use a `Selector` to switch between reading/writing/accepting to allow blocking only when theres nothing to do (to remove excess CPU usage)

```
class Server {
     private static Selector selector;
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
          ssc.configureBlocking(false);
          Selector selector = Selector.open();
          ssc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

          while(true) {
               selector.select();

               while(selector.iterator().hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = selector.iterator().next();

                    if(key.isAcceptable()) {
                         accept(key);
                    }
               }
          }
     }

     private static void accept(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
          ServerSocketChannel channel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
          SocketChannel sc = channel.accept();
          sc.register(selector, OP_READ);
     }
}
```

`SelectionKey` supports accepting via `isAcceptable()`, reading via `isReadable()` and writing via `isWritable()`, so you can handle all 3 on the same thread.

This is a basic example of accepting a connection using NIO. I highly suggest looking into it a bit more to get a better understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the API documentation of the class `Socket` from [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

Sockets are such a basic abstraction of network communication that you'd be hard pushed to find an OS which doesn't support them, let alone a high level programming language.

Comment: +1 In case there was any doubt, Javadoc says `Since:
JDK1.0`

Comment: I upvoted this since it answered the original question, but please see the edit for what the answer should be now.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner The answer is you can't. As I said, sockets are a network abstraction that is handled on the OS level already, the only way to avoid using them is to program the network interface layer directly, essentially writing a new device driver for your network card. And even then due to the way IP addressing works, you'll probably end up with something that is a socket in all but name.