# How to tell if Java SSLSocket has data available?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

When I was using regular Sockets, I could call getInputStream() and use available() to see how many bytes were available. I switched to SSLSocket, but now available() always returns 0 for some reason. When I read instead, I can still get data. How can I tell if there is data available in an SSLSocket so that I can service it without blocking if there is no data?

Notes:

- I cannot call read() on the InputStream or the thread will block. I would like non-blocking in my implementation.
- available() returns 0 even though there is data for SSLSocket's InputStream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does InputStream.available() do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695372/what-does-inputstream-available-do-in-java) (check out the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3695378/2398375))

Comment: That is interesting. However, in my case, there is data available, therefore read() should not be blocking, and available should not return 0.

Comment: Check out the first comment to that answer as well - "*Note also that available() always returns zero for an SSL socket*". It would help to know why blocking is a problem in your case. Keep in mind, you are using blocking IO

Comment: Ah I see. Then does that mean there is no way to tell that there is data in an SSLSocket without reading from it?

Comment: Blocking is theoretically not a problem other than I need to refactor a lot of my code. I used Sockets instead of SSLSockets previously and used available(), so I was hoping the transition would be easier.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your streams using `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62903/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-aura). It's best to keep the comment section clean. I will post as an answer once the problem has been solved.

Comment: BufferedInputStream is exhibiting the same behavior. I might be content to wrap the regular Socket and do encryption at the application level if there is no good answer.

Comment: Please discuss this in the chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Your streams cannot tell you the length of the data without first decrypting it. `available()` will *always* return 0 for `SSLSocket`.

As mentioned in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62903/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-aura), the reason you wanted to check for data is to prevent `read()` from blocking when called, so you can handle multiple connections on a single thread, instead of a *Thread per Client* system.

Instead, use a non-blocking alternative. `java.nio` currently doesn't have it's own SSL implementation of `SocketChannel`, but you can find one online (like [here](http://www.rmiproxy.com/ScalableSSL/javadoc/scalablessl/SSLSocketChannel.html)) or create your own.

With this system, you can register a `Selector` to every channel, and manage them all using the "selector thread". I wrote an example of how to use a selector [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616774/non-socket-based-java-server/24617983#24617983) (scroll down to **Using a Selector**).

With non-blocking IO, you to handle multiple clients per thread, allowing you to scale up. This method of managing channels was brought up due to the [C10k Problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you fixed your problem, but for those like me, I found a much easier solution. If you perform a read, then the available() method fills up for what was decrypted. How to use and abuse this? Read a single byte with a very low SoTimeout on your socket, if you catch a SocketTimeoutException, then the connection is empty, if not, prepend that byte you read to your future interpretation of the message. Until in.available() == 0 again, just roll with it.

Comment: Thanks @JavaProphet, this simple workaround came in handy for a proof of concept I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use available() with inputStream of underlying Socket. This works in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).