# Socket server multi-threading resources issue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I am working on a project like HQ trivia where multiple clients connect to server and submit their answers for a question, for that i have written code in java where users connect to a ServerSocket and a new thread is created for each client. There can be hundreds of thousands of clients. while testing for only 100 clients server reaches to 95% of CPU usage. i have provided some of the code below. if anybody could help me with an efficient way of dealing with that much client would be really appreciated

> Source for Main Class

```
public class Server {

            //static ServerSocket variable
            private static ServerSocket server;
            //socket server port on which it will listen
            private static int port = 9876;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            ClientWorker w;
            try{
                //server.accept returns a client connection
                System.out.println("Waiting for a connection to accept.");
                w = new ClientWorker(server.accept(), this);
                Thread t = new Thread(w);
                t.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.out.println("Accept failed: 9876");
                  System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

> Runnable Client Worker class

```
class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
    Server server;
    private Socket client;
    private String clientName = "";
    private String id = "";

    PrintStream printStream;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    //Constructor
    ClientWorker(Socket client, Server server) {
        this.client = client;
        this.server= server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            printStream = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            while(client.isConnected())
            {
                String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                //Some logical operation on users message
                printStream.println("response");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Server Specs are   HDD: 451G  CPU : 24  RAM: 16G

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You'll want a non-blocking implementation - use `SocketChannel` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617983/2398375)) or a pre-existing framework like Netty. Also see the [C10k problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).